# how to use ejabberdctrl set_vcard with non latin words in values?

Tags: ejabberd

version that I use:
ejabberd **16.01** is running in that node

Filling values of set_vcard/set_vcard2 with non latin symbols (for example, in russian - НА РУССКОМ) cause errors.

this construction works fine:

```
ejabberdctl set_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local FN "27 operator"
ejabberdctl set_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local NICKNAME "27 operator"
```

but if I want fill it with Cyrillic words like this:

```
ejabberdctl set_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local FN "27 Оператор"
ejabberdctl set_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local NICKNAME "27 Оператор"
```

it not works, in current version of ejabberd,  but in earlier versions this command line worked fine.

---

```
error output:

Problem 'error {case_clause,
                   {'EXIT',
                       {{badmatch,{error,{fread,character}}},
                        [{ejabberd_ctl,format_arg2,2,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,336}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,format_arg,2,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,327}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,'-format_args/2-fun-0-',2,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,318}]},
                         {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1262}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,220}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,205}]}]}}}' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,220}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,205}]},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                  [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]
Problem 'error {case_clause,
                   {'EXIT',
                       {{badmatch,{error,{fread,character}}},
                        [{ejabberd_ctl,format_arg2,2,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,336}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,format_arg,2,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,327}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,'-format_args/2-fun-0-',2,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,318}]},
                         {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1262}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,220}]},
                         {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                             [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,205}]}]}}}' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,220}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,205}]},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                  [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]
```

Please, tell how solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using ejabberd 18.01 and 19.08. I cannot try older ejabberd versions because they do not compile with my current Erlang.

```
$ ejabberdctl get_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local FN
error_no_vcard_found

$ ejabberdctl set_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local FN "27 Оператор"

$ ejabberdctl get_vcard user27 jabber.mydomain.local FN
27 Оператор
```

> Please, tell how solve this problem?

Install a newer ejabberd version, which probably has that problem solved. I don't know which exact version solved it. You can install ejabberd in a test machine, check if that feature works correctly, and then focus in installing it in your online server.

Comment: dumps of old base v.16 not restored, and try to copy old base dir - service ejabberd crashes on start, because of this installed fresh 18.01 and use now empty base.
Registered users, add New Shared Roster Groups, but no one see other users, only self.
Where is another "magic word" in config to do it?